# Every children do same thing but with time interval

Tags: jquery

I want `#house` children images to add class `.active` but not at the same time (currently my script does that), Firstly I want first `img` element to get class `.active` then second and loop infinitely

```
    function ind(){
        $('#house').children().toggleClass('active');
    }
    setInterval(ind,2000);
```

```html
        <div id="house">
            <img class="saxli" src="saxli.png">
            <img class="roof" src="roof.png">
            <img class="door" src="door.png">
            <img class="sabole" src="sabole.png">
            <img class="window1" src="window1.png">
            <img class="window2" src="window2.png">
        </div>
```

```css
        .active {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to work out within the `ind()` function that's called every 2 seconds, which element has the `active` class and then move it to the next `img`. If no elements have the class, or the last element has the class, make the first `img` active again. Try this:

```js
var $imgs = $('#house img');

function ind() {
  var $current = $imgs.filter('.active').removeClass('active');
  var $target = $current.next();
  if ($target.length === 0)
    $target = $imgs.first();
    
  $target.addClass('active');
}

ind(); // call on page load
setInterval(ind, 2000); // call every 2 seconds
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.active {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="house">
  <img class="saxli" src="saxli.png">
  <img class="roof" src="roof.png">
  <img class="door" src="door.png">
  <img class="sabole" src="sabole.png">
  <img class="window1" src="window1.png">
  <img class="window2" src="window2.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of a position and increment/reset it. You can do something like this:

```
function ind(){
  ind.children = ind.children || $('#house').children();
  ind.pos = ind.pos <= ind.children.length && ind.pos || 0;
  ind.children.removeClass('active');
  $(ind.children[ind.pos++]).addClass('active');

}
setInterval(ind,2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r2zw4xks/

*Note: I added a border to the class since the jsfiddle doesn't include pictures, so you can visually see it*

Comment: @LevanCharuashvili I appreciate the Marked Solved but **RoryMcCrosssan** posted basically the same thing several minutes before me! (_somehow my page didn't update to show his answer when I posted_)